# Do moderators want link-only answer flags, or not?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, link-only-answers

Here are two examples which I recently flagged as link-only answers:

Example 1:

> Try this: `{link}`

Example 2:

> i think this will be help ful: `{link}`

I think we can all agree that these two answers, given that they both have no content aside from a link, are of equal value, so you would think the degree of helpfulness of those two flags would, correspondingly, be equal.

But, no. Flagging Example 2 gets lauded as helpful, but upon flagging Example 1 I am told to go away and leave the moderators alone.

[image]

So, which is it? Do moderators want these link-only answer flags, or not?

Just let me know, and I'll happily go along.

I am currently banned from flagging content, in no small part because too many of my recent link-only answer flags have been declined*. The system lectures me that I have to go back and look at my flags. I want to learn, I really do, but excuse me if the conclusions and proposed course of action aren't exactly self-evident here.

<sub>* Another reason is that I may have been a bit excessive on the not-an-answer button on a few occasions, fair enough, but that's a discussion for another day.</sub>

Comment: Very Related: [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers), which is a dup of the post @Patrick mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using a custom flag reason, which is wrong and indeed taking time from mods while the community could have handled it.

Flag as Not an answer (NAA) instead. Those flags will end up in the [LQ review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats).

Also see this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/245360) post on NAA that states that link-only answers are indeed 'not an answer' (note that it doesn't say anything on *when and if* you should flag it for that). Also note the fine line when an answer is considered link only or not.

Comment: Ah, so NAA goes to the community review queue, while custom flags go to moderators? If that's it, then ok, I get it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Yes indeed. Updated the post.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett NAA goes to both the community and the mods.  If the mods get to it first or the community disputes it, they will handle it, but if the community agrees with your flag, it will get marked as helpful.

Comment: And, repeatedly just placing _link only answer_ as a flag with no additional attempt to improve the answer isn't exactly the behavior we want.  It could be possible that the "link answer" is the only answer to the question, it might actually be incredibly helpful - so losing this might not be making the internet better.  First, we'd prefer commenting to the user to improve the answer, attempting to improve the answer via an edit or even posting a new answer with link details before any flags get sent to a moderator to delete/remove.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in @shog9's guidance where he says to blanket flag link-only answers as "Not an Answer." Could you quote the relevant sections for me?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I didn't say he said so, did I?

Comment: Yes: "Also see this meta post on NAA that states that link-only answers are indeed 'not an answer'."

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Yes. They are. I didn't say to 'blanket flag them'. I even pointed out that not every post containing a link is link-only.

Comment: You may not have said it, but depending on who reads it, it may be interpreted that way.  I am with @GeorgeStocker on this that you could clarify that point a little better.