# Some link-only answers are immune?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635846/663028

> Google wrote some code to assist with this. Here's an example:
>   <link>
>
> Here are other styled marker examples:
>   <link>
>
> And another:
>   <link>

I don't care about the flag rate, but it appears neither Other or NAA would be accepted (I am *not* going to try Spam or Offensive). If this is the prevailing site policy, please make this clearer.

Comment: Link-only answers are controversial. So be aware that you are walking a fuzzy line when you flag them. I would also assume that moderators are more hesitant to delete massively upvoted posts.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah I saw some of the related discussions. I just want to point out that these answers are no less vulnerable to link-rot and usual problems of LAA

Comment: see **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)** "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*..."

Comment: I guess what I really want to ask is: should something be done, what can be done (and by who), and if nothing can/should be done, make it explicit enough in the faqs

Comment: It's a bad question and a bad answer. The question has now been locked and I left a comment on the answer asking to expand on what he meant since he's still an active user. If he does not adapt the answer I'll custom flag it as well, as should you.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel fair enough, I will do that

Comment: update: answerer has [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5635846/revisions "see rev 2") their post into better (_much better_) shape

Answer (score 0):

When you cast a moderator flag on an answer, what you're asking for by default is for the moderator to *delete the answer.*  Moderators are not likely to do that to accepted answers having a large number of upvotes.

Instead of moderator-flagging the answer, why not fix it? You've got editing rights; write in a summary.  That way you preserve the answer in a form suitable to the community without destroying valuable information.

Comment: As a person interested in the question, I found that answer to be irrelevant and I cannot be expected to pick the author's brains to prove the contrary. How about asking those people who upvoted it? Then again voting is supposed to be secret, so we are at an impasse. Good luck.

Comment: You did ask. ...

Comment: have you tried fixing this yourself? I tried - not to help lazy answerer mind you, merely to save self rep-loss from voting it down - couldn't squeeze _anything_ sensible from links dumped in there

Comment: We need a canonical dupe target for such posts now. This discussion comes up every alternate day on MSO.

Comment: @Sunshine I guess that would be one of [Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251609/839601) or [Do moderators want link-only answer flags, or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272982/839601)

Comment: @Sunshine I think you are missing the point, this discussion comes up again because there appears to be no consensus resulting from the so-called canonical post, at least it hasn't been acted upon consistently, in my recent experience. I want the status to be made clearer, as it was unclear enough that I ended up having to ask a similar question.

Comment: @prusswan: Let's just say I am fairly active on MSO and am aware of the discussions on this topic. I am not going to engage in this discussion with you :)

Comment: ah, how can I forget the usual MSO snobbery

Comment: @pru: snobbery? I flag a lot (including accepted link-only NAAs) and the mods delete them when they are valid cases. My experience as well as the data published on MSO coincide, valid flags rarely get declined. Your question on the other hand is based on an empty assumption that if you flag, it might get declined. If you really care about the site, flag and see if it gets declined or not. Empty assumptions are not constructive. Posts regarding real flags aren't closed as dupes, the hollow ones are. Before we expect mods to act, we need to act. We too, are responsible for SO's quality.

Comment: and I did act far beyond the responsibility as an average user. The inconsistency should not have happened and result in the filing of this question, since the last "consensus". If moderators cannot agree among themselves, normal users certainly could care less. People should have more respect of other people's time, even for normal users. Just imagine how many people tried to make sense of that answer and the time wasted

Comment: @prusswan: [Well, actually...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om7O0MFkmpw)