# What is the policy to delete old up-voted link only answers those cannot be edited in shape?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, link-only-answers, rules

I recently flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101081/5779732) answer as Not An Answer being Link-Only answer.

[image: Answer]

My flag was marked helpful. Question was closed as Too Broad. But the answer is not deleted.

The NAA flag indicates that the post is not useful because links may go dead in future. It is always recommended on Stack Overflow that answer body itself should contain the relevant information from the link. Link should be provided for additional read. This is explained in details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).

I have flagged similar answers (old, up-voted) as NAA in past and those were deleted. I have avoided the [old mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365145/5779732) this time.

I read [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280062/5779732) [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251609/5779732) questions on Meta. Those suggest instead of deleting such answers, better edit them in shape. Problem with this answer is that, it cannot be edited in shape as the link is pointing to the [book](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly). Question itself is too broad. Relevant part from book will be too large to make it a good answer.

What is the policy to delete old up-voted link only answers those cannot be edited in shape?

Although, I mentioned specific answer in this question, **I would like to learn general policy** instead of comments/answers for this specific answer.

Comment: Just don't retro-actively apply recent post requirements to old posts.  Especially anything from 2008 and 2009, there were no requirements yet back then.  It wasn't until October 2009 that they figured out and agreed about what kind of Q+A works.  Too late to whack them now, that will break the Internet.

Comment: Interestingly enough, another link-only answer on the same question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5274396/7296893)) got deleted by a mod 4 days ago.

Comment: What is the problem if the answer is just left alone? It was posted shortly after the site went live, it has 18 upvotes, no downvotes, the link still works, the question kind of asks for these kind of answers and has plenty of views. What is the itch that makes that you click flag in the first place? A moderator is free to take any or no action based on a raised flag and based on what they find mark the flag helpful or not. If you want to be sure that a post gets deleted by a mod, raise a custom flag and tell them so. Don't be surprised if Undo would have declined that flag in this case.

Comment: @Hans IMO we should apply modern standards to questions, and close them, but just not delete them (to send a clear message that such content is no longer acceptable, but not delete high-view content)

Comment: @Erik - you can ask a moderator for a "historical lock".  Sends the right signal.

Comment: It's closed now, good enough for me, no new answers at least. People should know that most answers to closed questions are not appropriate (we close to prevent those).

Comment: @rene: **"What is the problem if the answer is just left alone?"**. No; I do not have any problem. As I said in the question, I just wanted to understand the **general policy** because there was difference in handling similar flag.

Comment: @HansPassant: **"there were no requirements yet back then. It wasn't until October 2009 that they figured out and agreed about what kind of Q+A works.."**. That is something I learned now. Thanks.

Comment: Using such logic, millions of questions should be closed and deleted since they are no longer on topic. In practice, we don't do it. Just leave it be. If you don't like an answer, downvote it. That's what the downvotes are for. No need to delete everything you don't like.

Comment: I may hope the general policy will be that you don't flag that old stuff and if you still do ask for an historical lock as Hans proposed. Difference in handling is because mods are humans to.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I do not WANT that the answer to be deleted. And I did not flagged it just because I don't like it. I flagged it because SO defines it as NAA and suggests to flag it so. First part of your comment is helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @AmitJoshi so what exactly did you expect to achieve by flagging, if not delete the answer? There's no special "NAA" mark that moderators can place on answers. They can either delete the answer, or not. They won't go and edit it into shape, it's not their job.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: My flag was correct; that is why it is marked as helpful. So flag/not-flag should not be an issue. And you are correct. When I flagged NAA in past, the answer was deleted. So yes, that was what I was expecting (NOT willing to) here. Because, there was different behavior this time, I wanted to learn why? As I said in question, I am not talking about this specific answer; I am expecting general comments/answers. Linked answer is just an example.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more welcoming to remove these kinds of answers so that new users are not left feeling bad because their similarly link-only answers were deleted, but not these?

Comment: @rene Lots of previous meta posts indicate that people should flag old answers that break current rules. [Example 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060/9614249). [Example 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194221). [Example 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194117). That last answer in particular even says "View all question with today's standards. If the question fits as per current standards then leave it open; if it doesn't fit then vote/flag to close it. If we keep the questions which don't fit as per current standards, then people will ask why the questions are still open".

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic that example 3 is about questions where I still hold the position: if it doesn't do any harm, leave it alone. We don't have enough users around that are willing to sift through the close vote queue (it is at 9K or so) and we certainly don't have enough moderators to handle all the flags. For some unexplainable reason enough users have no problem to go digging for crap but once it comes to handling the reviews resulting from those flags everyone left the building. It is not that I don't agree we can do without them but today we have more pressing matters to solve.

Comment: @rene I wouldn't recommend people go digging things up, but if they happen across something not in line with the standards I think it should be flagged. The fact that someone came across it years later means it is being visited and should be corrected, regardless of how full the flag queue is. Telling people not to flag things because the queue is full seems like a bad idea. Under that reasoning we could stop flagging things on low traffic tags because it is not worth the time.

Comment: To be clear, I still want flags on old stuff (and even digging it up!). Don't take this as "give old stuff a pass", it's more "I chose to whack the question instead of the answer". A full flag queue is mostly fine, we have ways to filter it.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic if we agree on the don't dig things up I'm fine with the rest. Just don't go looking for trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was link only. The question was asking for broad answers, inviting link only ones. I blamed the question, and marked your flag helpful.

It's a judgement call, varying between moderators and with the position of the Moon. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: This. If the question is off-topic, no need to waste time, effort, and votes dealing with the 8 questionable answers it received.

Comment: The most important part here is the position of the Moon.

Answer (score 4):

Going solely off of previous Meta posts it seems the correct action is to flag it and let a moderator decide the correct course of action.

The most relevant [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194117) I found by [hims056](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/187824/hims056) says:

> View all question with today's standards. If the question fits as per [current standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) then leave it open; if it doesn't fit then vote/flag to close it. If we keep the questions which don't fit as per current standards, then people will ask why the questions are still open.

I would assume it is fairly safe to say the same line of thinking applies to answers as well.

If you come across an old answer that doesn't fit in with today's standards it is likely the question may need some moderator action, just like what happened in your particular case.

If you happen across an old answer just flag it and let the moderators decide whether the answer needs to be deleted, a historical lock should be placed, the question closed, etc.

Comment: *just flag it and let the system decide* which system is that?

Comment: @rene [The review queue/moderation system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: Don't forget that the system is run by human slaves, and a few dogs ...