# Merge the "Not An Answer" and "Very Low Quality" flags into one

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

*Note, there is [a similar request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214583) which is 2 years old.*

*Note also that the observations made here can be put in perspective of [the comment flag change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252844/make-comment-flags-less-stupid) which is going to encapsulate lots of comment flag types into a single one, for the same reasons that will be described in this post.*

*This post is **not** about stating the current difference between the NAA and VLQ flags. Its purpose is **not** to make consensus on when to choose one over the other. **Its purpose is to merge those two flags into one and coming up with a unifying simple process for both users and moderators**.*

Let me start by an overview of the current workflow for both flags.

- "Not An Answer": When this flag is raised, the post goes into the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, [unless the answer is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253449). If a reviewer from that queue edits the post, the flag is automatically cleared. [The flag is not cleared if the post is edited outside of the queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317427/1743880). If the result of the review is "Looks OK", [the flag is disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277). If the result of review is "Recommend Deletion", the post is deleted and the flag is marked helpful. At any time, a moderator can review the flag and either decline it, accept it by marking the flag helpful (and generally deleting the post in the process [or converting it to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196377)).
- "Very Low Quality": When this flag is raised, the post goes into the "Low Quality Posts" review queue [after a delay of 15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203217), unless the answer is accepted. It is not possible to flag as VLQ a post with score > 0. Whenever the post is edited, whether it is in the queue or not, whether the editor is the flagger themselves or not, the flag is marked helpful and the post gets an automatic downvote. If the result of the review is "Looks OK", [the flag is disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277). If the result of review is "Recommend Deletion", the post is deleted and the flag is marked helpful. At any time, a moderator can review the flag and either decline it or accept it by marking the flag helpful (and generally deleting the post in the process or converting it to a comment).

Those two flags have a very different usage guidance. For NAA:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

whereas for VLQ:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Putting into perspective the usage guidance of the flags and the difference in their workflow, something is clearly wrong. Those two flags are intended to be used differently depending of the content of the answer, but they are handled exactly the same way, have practically the same workflow and both have the same meaning:

> I think this answer should be deleted (either converted to a comment or removed altogether).

The result is more often than not a confusion over which flag to choose: [Am I misusing the “Very Low Quality” flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265573/1743880) — [The Very Low Quality flag is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268269/1743880) — [Making sure the “Not an answer” flag is used for non-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95659) — [Difference between 'very low quality' and 'not an answer' flags](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2918). The result of the confusion is always the same: a pedantic red-circle emphasizing specific words out of the context of the flag description that ought to explain why you did something wrong. It's even worse if you consider link-only answers: [Should link-only answers be flagged as not-an-answer? Conflicting meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303115/1743880) — [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183603)

Therefore, to simplify this, I suggest merging those two flags into a single one. Those would be the clear advantages:

- Single clear point of entry for users to flag an answer with serious issues and not meeting the quality criteria and Q/A format required by Stack Overflow.
- Single flag for moderators to handle, thereby easying their filtering and flag handling processes.

This would be the workflow of the proposed flag:

- Flag can be raised <strike>whatever the score of the answer</strike> if the answer has a score ≤ 0 (as per [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one?noredirect=1#comment321920_318952)). Currently, this is the case for VLQ but not for NAA;
- The answer goes into the "Low Quality Posts" queue, unless it is accepted, where it follows exactly the same process as today (if accepted, it goes directly into the moderator queue). [4 "Recommend Deletion" actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344886/1743880) or 3 "Delete" votes by users with 20k+ reputation will delete the answer if its score is ≤ 0 and will raise a system flag if its score is > 0, [just like today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092).
- An edit made by the OP or by someone from the queue would mark the flag helpful. This would stop the current loop-hole and potential abuse where someone can flag as VLQ and immediately edit, thereby marking the flag helpful. Also, the current VLQ flag description says the post *"is unlikely to be salvageable through editing"*, but the flag is marked helpful when the post is edited, meaning that if the post was editable to a useful state then the flag was wrong.
- A system flag would be raised if the result of the review in the "Low Quality Posts" queue is disputed, [just like today for both flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/1743880).
- Moderators would still be able to handle the flag at any time, just like they do now (deleting, converting to comment, declining).

The name of the new flag is up for discussion, but it should convey the intent that what is being flagged is intended for deletion.

Comment: For consistency with the review queues, we could name the flag "unsalvageable."

Comment: Honestly, I like the name "Not an answer" or a variation, but that might carry too much baggage from the past.  How about "malformed answer" or (report this answer as) "having severe content problems"?

Comment: _'If the result of review is "Recommend Deletion", the post is deleted'_ -- this is [not exactly so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299376/839601). If post gets positive score or accept mark at the moment of review completion, deletion is postponed until moderator decides on it. Also worth noting that automatic downvote to post flagged VLQ is [revoked if it later gets an upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266436/165773)

Comment: I want to upvote this request, but I have my doubts - about if it will really solve anything. The goal as I see it is to remove or severely lessen ambiguity; it would have to be a darned aptly named and described flag to achieve that, just turning two flags into one isn't necessarily going to make it easier to reason when to apply it, nor to see why it was applied to your answer. So far I have invented a new dimension of coming up blank regarding that flag name :/

Comment: _"Single clear point of entry for users to flag an answer that does not meet the quality criteria and Q/A format required by Stack Overflow."_ -> Don't we have downvotes for that? Those flags are only for serious __issues__ that have to be removed rather quickly.

Comment: @Cerbrus Downvotes are not for questions posted as answer, this is what I meant by "not meeting the Q/A format". But I'll clarify with the word "issues". Thanks.

Comment: Some quick data on answers with helpful VLQ and NAA flags during the past 90 days: 79% NAA, 29% VLQ, 9% both. https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=v&chs=200x100&chd=t:91,29,0,9&chdl=NAA|VLQ - that's just under 10K answers (or a bit over 100 answers per day) that are ONLY getting VLQ flags right now.

Comment: @Shog9 Such a tiny chart! Here it is a bit bigger https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=v&chs=600x300&chd=t:91,29,0,9&chdl=NAA|VLQ :)

Comment: Regarding flags on upvoted posts... During the last 90 days, about 60% of NAA flags raised on upvoted posts were helpful, vs. 94% for those scoring <= 0. Even when deemed helpful by review, these posts still require a moderator to actually delete (a separate flag is raised for this) - only 44% of NAA flags on upvoted answers resulted in the answer's deletion. As a rule, flags on upvoted answers are more of a nuisance than an aid; folks are more likely to use them for answers they don't *like* (or that match some simple pattern) than for true non-answers.

Comment: @Shog9 So instead of being able to flag whatever the score, you would suggest to only be able to flag is the score is <=0? Thanks for those numbers, it indeed sounds very reasonable. I'll edit with that.

Comment: What's missing in that comment is a sense of scale, @Tunaki: out of the hundreds of NAA flags raised every day, only a few dozen are on upvoted answers. I'll post an answer with more detail when I get time (not this morning), but I want to give you a rough idea of the shape of the problem here, namely: we need flags that match up to flaggers' understanding of issues that can be handled by moderators/reviewers. This is where the oft-proposed "delete this" flag falls apart: there are countless reasons to want something deleted that shouldn't actually result in a deletion.

Comment: One last note... You linked to a discussion on Chemistry but posted this on MSO. I'm fine discussing this in the context of Stack Overflow, but you should realize that the challenges facing moderators (and flaggers) on smaller sites are very different. SO gets more NAA/VLQ flags in a day than Chemistry does in a quarter-year; arguably *neither* flag is necessary on such small sites, but they exist for the sake of consistency.

Comment: VLQ tends to be interpreted as VLE (effort) which causes the decline flags.

Comment: NAA needs to lose all the terminology relating to comments and other things, it just needs to say, "This is gibberish and not spam", because everything else gets declined because of the extremely liberal application of what **attempt** at an answer means.

Comment: Most NAA flags are helpful, @Jarrod. Folks get twisted up about edge cases (same problem you observed in VLQ, really - folks flagging answers because they're short) but most of the time flaggers do get it right.

Comment: Link-only NAAs often have upvotes.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - there is no such thing as a link only NAA, a link only is an **attempt** to answer, just a really lazy one, but an attempt and will get declined.

Comment: @Shog9 - I do not disagree, but the "should be a comment, etc" trips people up because they read that is you will move it to a comment, but there is no judgement calls like that anymore, so until someone can expound on why they think it is NAA, then it should just say. ***This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.*** the *It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.* infers that the person acting will make a judgement call on comment, edit or deleted. That just does not happen anymore, instead it is **declined**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson [well,  Shog9 disagrees](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Shog9 does not personally review every NAA flag, the the overwhelming evidence is the other mods will just decline, and if you complain on meta you are just told to edit it so it is not link only anymore.

Comment: The "link only" thing is actually a pretty good example of a situation where the flag type either doesn't matter, or the post shouldn't be flagged at all, @Jarrod. In my experience, this notion that there are these brilliant answers out there that should nevertheless be deleted because they're "link-only" is... Kinda bunk; there are plenty of very-low-quality non-answers consisting only of a link, a handful of cases where the proper answer literally *is* a link, and a whole lot of terse answers that happen to contain links. No one argues about #1, human regexps flag #2 and bitter folk flag #3.

Comment: @Shog9 - I am not disagreeing, it is just my opinion that the text in the flags needs to be changed to reflect what you posted for case #1 and nothing else.

Comment: @BhargavRao *up for discussion* neither.

Comment: Yeah @Knu, I wanna rollback that :-(

Comment: @Shog9 I've been in plenty of arguments regarding #1.

Answer (score 71):

Let me first say that (as a moderator) I no longer perform the calculus it takes to determine whether a not a non-answer answer flag is really hooked to a not a non-answer answer.  If the answer merits deletion, I delete it.  If I can't figure out why the answer was flagged, I decline the flag.  That's it.

The problem is not so much the workflow (which you've described in detail, thanks); it's the *review audit* system.  This system takes cues from the way the moderator flags are handled in order to find candidates it can use for audits.  Any change to the way people flag things would have to take that into account.

I'm in favor of any sensible suggestion that would remove the "not an answer" verbiage, as I think the community spends far more time worrying about what the definition of "is" is than the issue merits.

The flag's description would have to be chosen carefully.  Any replacement flag (and its corresponding verbiage) would have to answer to everyone's satisfaction the question: "What is wrong with this post that makes it harmful enough to the site to merit forcible removal by a moderator?"

Comment: One concern I have is the community does not want to downvote answers that should be downvoted; rather they want moderators to delete them (perhaps due to loss aversion). This ends up increasing the workload on the part of 12 people when thousands downvoting would make a much bigger impact.  There's still a desire to use flagging where downvoting would be appropriate; and I don't see how this question (or your answer) solves that particularly thorny issue. I still upvoted it; but that's a big concern I have about removing the NAA flag.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker some of the down voting hesitation might be solvable via better education; the Roomba returns rep points used to fuel down votes when it takes out the trash.

Comment: @George Of course, removing the 1 point hit for downvoting answers would also help remove the disincentive for downvoting answers... Or alternatively, add a 1 point hit for flagging NAA/VLQ.

Comment: There is probably a loss aversion factor involved, @George, but if I'm reading the Meta discussions right, it is far beyond that. These people have a burning desire to get the content *removed* from the site. It is, for some reason, bothering them that it is exists. Downvoting will not satisfy them. Since they're not 10k+ (or 20k+), they can't vote to delete, so they do the only thing they can do: flag. (And/or use a chat room to crowd-source the deletion.)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I, for one, avoid downvoting VLQ/NAA posts from new users. It's often taken as "you suck, go away". That the user was trying to be helpful only adds insult to injury. I sometimes downvote in combination with a friendly comment, but I don't have time and patience to make dozens of those daily (and so do few other reviewers). A quiet delete is often the best thing IMHO. Perhaps I should be less worried about offending folk, but that's how I am and I don't think I'm so special in this regard, and the system should adapt to human psychology when possible, not the other way around!

Comment: I wonder if it would help if the VLQ/NAA queues had an option of "This is a valid answer, but it deserves a downvote."  If enough people choose that option, the answer gets a downvote with no penalty to the reviewers.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know if I've ever flagged an answer for NAA or VLQ, but I can certainly understand the desire to get bad content out of people's way. Maybe some people aren't as good as others at tempering that desire with the knowledge that perhaps not everyone shares their viewpoint, especially when we see low quality content regularly upvoted.

Comment: `I'm in favor of any sensible suggestion that would remove the "not an answer" verbiage, as I think the community spends far more time worrying about what the definition of "is" is than the issue merits.`
Totally agree.

Comment: Robert [created a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318998/3956566) to help solve the issue of the flag name and reason. Whether it should be under here or as a new post?

Comment: Something has to be really wrong for me to downvote because of the cost. I'm trying to get to 10k because I want more privileges to help with the site moderation. But if I'm spending points downvoting, it makes it harder to get there. I downvote when I want to encourage the answerer to delete the answer to get his rep back.

Comment: The loss of rep from downvoting makes it feel like you're "not supposed" to downvote. It feels like you're breaking the rules and doing something wrong by downvoting.

Comment: @Almo Tell me about it, I'd be `+10k` if it wasn't for downvoting...

Answer (score 41):

The new flag should just be called “delete”. It should work like close flags do: bring the post to a review queue (the current low quality queue), and not be shown to moderators. There should be proper guidance indicating deletion reasons, just like there are close reasons.

Speaking as a moderator¹, I'd rather not have any restriction on score or accepted status. This lets the community give their say about the handling of a post. As already happens in the VLQ workflow now, if a high-scoring (I guess ≥1 is the right threshold) or accepted answer reaches a “delete” verdict from the community, then raise a moderator flag.

¹  <sub>Not on SO, but I don't see why SO would have different rules here.</sub>

Comment: What would the flag description be in the pop up?

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW "content in this answer deserves deletion". Workflow suggested here would better involve flagger's [accountability for (currently harmless) disputed flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243187/165773), to prevent spamming review queue by those who "don't get it". Or maybe we could get rid of "disputed" at all and replace it with declined, like it already happens to flags to close

Comment: @gnat yes something like and you are suggesting a link? I like the idea of a link.. it's gives something to point to if people then complain and you never know, some people might go there! :D I think the getting rid of disputed flags is better dealt with in a separate post though, it's ambiguous if voting on >1 issue

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW link to Help Center or to some meta FAQ would be good to have, the easier it would be for flagger to get to it, the better

Comment: I hate to say this, I think I prefer this to my own suggestion. So simple, which is why I missed it, if there's a half-assed complicated way of achieving something I seem to find it!!! LOLOL

Comment: This sounds indeed simple and yet powerful enough. Perfect!

Comment: We already have a 'delete' option, I'm not sure I understand how this would really be different except removing the 'must have negative score' and allow lower rep folks to do it.  Just change those...

Comment: @Joe We have three delete options: “very low quality” flag, “not an answer” flag, and “delete” vote (requiring 20k rep). My point is that these should be unified — keeping just a flag/vote distinction based on rep, like the way it works for closing.

Comment: So, pretty much [waffles' old proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous#comment234821_93606) that was [shot down immediately by Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous#comment234823_93606) (as being 'nonsensical') back in the day?

Comment: @GitaarLAB That thread mostly focused on questions, but otherwise, yes, waffles had the right idea back then.

Comment: I think it does make sense. What about expanding this: make it `delete because...` where the `...` means (just like `close` >> `off-topic because...`) that a second option-list follows with the (historical) common reasons NAA, VLQ (but better defined) and optional new reason(s) the community feels that are lacking (like *perhaps for example* `an answer but not to this question` or `non-english`)?

Comment: @GitaarLAB Yes, that's how it would work (like “close” → several reasons, I don't think there's a need for delete reasons with yet another level like there is with sub-reasons of “off-topic”).

Comment: Delete says nicely what it does but not why. I would rather flag for a reason, not for an action.

Comment: @Trilarion Which is why “delete” should lead to a box where you select a reason. Just like close. You flag **for** an action, **because** of a reason. A flag with no action is meaningless.

Comment: Love it. Simple and to the point without having any hint of personal judgement to it.

Answer (score 18):

## New Flag Proposal.

*Perhaps if people could list feedback under here, or edit and with reason for changes. This is a community wiki.*

## Current Flags

**I'm assuming this is for answers only.**

Currently the two flag reasons are as follows:

**not an answer**

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. 
>   It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

**very low quality**

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. 
>   This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

## Solution

I suggest a refined merge of the two flags.

1. As it is for answers only, any reference to "answer" is redundant.

This <strike>was posted as an answer, but it</strike> does not attempt to answer the question.
This <strike>answer</strike> has severe formatting or content problems.

2. We don't need to refer to it being removed twice.

> It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

and

> This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

3. Name.

The flag could be named **The Low Quality Flag**, as it would bump posts into **The Low Quality Review Queue**.

4. Removing reference to formatting.

> I'm aware that it's currently there as well but I don't think that "severe" formatting problems is a valid reason to delete an answer. In fact formatting problems are maybe the one thing that can be fixed. You might want to remove that from the flag reason

-[From the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one#comment322203_318998)

5. Removing "It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."

> "It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." this needs to be removed completely, it just confuses people that use the flag thinking a mod is going to make a judgement call to move it to a comment, edit or delete it, it is really clear that right now that is not what is going to happen

-[From the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one/318998?noredirect=1#comment322375_318998)

## New Flag

**low quality**

> This does not attempt to answer the question or has severe content problems, and is unlikely to be salvageable through editing.

*Artist rendition*

[image]

I suggest with a link to the suitable place on Meta or in the FAQ.

Comment: I'm happy for the SO developers to use my image as is for the new flag box :D - No charge!

Comment: I'm aware that it's currently there as well but I don't think that "severe" formatting problems is a valid reason to delete an answer. In fact formatting problems are maybe the one thing that can be fixed. You might want to remove that from the flag reason.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the feedback, please see edit

Comment: I'm wondering/worrying if in its lowered intensity the flag name now misses the point. This flag is for severe content problems as per the description (which I do find perfectly fine), "low quality" covers a whole lot more than only the severe stuff. We downvote low quality stuff.

Comment: @Gimby agreed. As reflected in my message [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29343703#29343703) I think it would be better if we had a nice synonym for "shit quality"

Comment: @Gimby Yes I wondered that also. Any Ideas? Please feel free to write an answer or make an edit.

Comment: @TimCastelijns (and ms yvette) or something to do with missing the point. Because ultimately that's why its a catapult ammunition and not a downvote - the content entirely misses the point and needs to go. Right?

Comment: OR!!!! The **it hurts my eyes** flag!!!! Yes ?? :D @Gimby

Comment: No that's either a custom flag or if you're evil a meta burn ;)

Comment: **"It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."** this needs to be removed completely, it just confuses people that use the flag thinking a mod is going to make a judgement call to move it to a comment, edit or delete it, it is really clear that right now that is **not** what is going to happen.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Read: gibberish.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ***gibberish:** unintelligible or meaningless speech or writing; nonsense.* yes, I could live with that :p

Comment: I would stay with very low quality, not only low quality.

Comment: @Trilarion I somehow think the "delete" option of the other answer will be the new name :D

Answer (score 4):

Another more refined solution.

There's currently [184 questions about NAAs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=naa%20is%3Aquestion) and [234 on Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=very%20low%20quality%20flag%20%20is%3Aquestion) flags. This tends to lean that there's some misunderstanding on how to use these flags.

[image]

As with [comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag) simplify the flags,  and merge the two flags.

Keep it simple. Combining the two explanations. Use red to alert users what not to do and provide a link to convey that downvotes, not flags should be used for answers a user disagrees with or thinks is wrong.

[image]

There is currently an automatic downvote for VLQ flags, this would go and the user could then decide whether or not to apply a downvote when they flag, as an independent action and issue.

Comment: As commented elsewhere, I would love to have this, and it's on my to-insist-upon list. Combining NAA+VLQ into a more obvious and general "needs to be deleted" flag is a fantastic idea that is way past its time. A couple of thoughts, though. First off, with the current flag system, it really just doesn't matter which one you pick, because for all intents and purposes, they're treated the same. Moderators don't care, and the system doesn't either—they both dump into LQP review. Second, I think it's great that the community handle them, but us mods aren't over-pressured, so we can help, too.

Comment: @CodyGray ideally the spam/rude abusive flags could be combined - as the result of both is the same. The only thing is this affecting data collection - but there's a meta post *somewhere* I believe that states this isn't a problem. Maybe I should be chatting to you before posting these and we can make a collaborative effort.

Comment: The text in red (i.e. *"Not to be used for incorrect answers"*) would be a good addition regardless of the rest of the idea. I seem to recall several posts about people wrongly useing flags for incorrect answers.

Comment: I may've kinda buried the lede when discussing comment flags, but... The big fat problem we're attempting to address isn't so much that there were too many options, but that [the most time-sensitive option bled into one of the least](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298507/new-no-longer-needed-flag-reason-title-is-incorrect/298511#298511). Imagine if you called [the emergency hotline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_telephone_number) and occasionally got "current time"! That's very much *not* the case for VLQ / NAA though, which are quite similar in severity.

Comment: @Shog9 but what is stopping us from merging them? and even merging the rude/spam ones (do you need to differentiate between the two for data analysis?) I honestly believe a simplified UI will enhance the UX and assist in reducing the number of "incorrect" actions from users. The problem with the help centre is it's *too* comprehensive - we need it - it's the rule book, but we need clear international "street signs" posted on all actions. So we have a shorthand for the majority of people who just don't read the fine print on documents so to speak. what can we do to make this happen Shog8+1?

Comment: The most common incorrect action isn't picking the wrong flag, @yvette. It's flagging things that don't need to be moderated at all. It's not even a close race. We've actually debated adding a "this answer is wrong" option that just tells the flagger to downvote if chosen.

Comment: @Shog9 that's a good idea - I still vouch for simplicity - amalgamate flags that do the same thing (except remove the v low qual downvote and it will be the same). Add a clear red instruction to downvote instead of flag - which I added as incorrect answer - but this answer is wrong is probably simpler.

Comment: I'm not at all convinced it's a good idea, which is why we haven't done it; there's an argument to be made that it's manipulative and belittling. Keep in mind that [the vast, *vast* majority of all flags are helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i/340905#340905) - we'd be treating all flaggers like they were simple for the questionable benefit of a few who would quickly be corrected anyway. The question we should be asking in all of these discussions is "what sort of things do we want to see flagged?"