# Should I flag an answer that basically just links to my answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers, plagiarism

I posted an answer to a question. Now I saw that another user post another answer, which basically just links to my answer. The user's answer is:

> Here is a one-liner (stolen from Jonathan Mee's answer):
>   `for(size_t i = 0, s = a.size(); i < output.size(); ++i) output[i] = b[i/s] + ' ' + a[i%s];`
>   Full example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eae922caa44b93c).

Now the code is mine, and I even already had a live example in my code along with an explanation of what the code does.

I'd consider whether this is a link only answer and I should flag it; but frankly, I get the link only thing wrong as often as I get it right. Should I be flagging this answer?

Comment: So did the user add nothing new and all of the content in the answer is from your answer?

Comment: Close as duplicate now?

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean he did either copy paste, or retype my example into a different cloud compiler and provide that link instead of the link to my cloud compiler.

Comment: Well he did change using a `for_each` and a lambda into a regular for loop.  I am not sure if that qualifies as plagiarism or fair use.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ugh... this is not a dupe. I just read that as my code. Thank you for reading better than I do.

Comment: From what I see, it is an answer to the same question, not in another one. Am I right?

Comment: @fedorqui It is, but my code used a `for_each` and his code uses a `for` so there is a small change. NathanOliver had to point it out to me.

Comment: Indeed. I just mention it for those understanding it is a different one and suggesting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Related: [Copy-pasting the contents of another answer to the same question — with attribution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269396/119775)

Comment: According [to this Jeff Atwood post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) attribution is required and you **must**: 1) link to the original question/answer 2) explicitly mention the name of the authro and **3) link to the profile of the author**.

Comment: Not wanting to join the plagiarism discussion: I really don't understand how _"I turned someone else's answer into this oneliner"_ can be voted up more than the answer that presented the code in the first place.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think that's the meta-effect at work... It's specifically why I didn't link the answers. But, I suppose it can't be avoided.

Comment: [Technically the code is **not** yours, it is ceases to be *yours* when you submit it to SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: I had a user downvote an answer of mine when my Regex was one tiny smidge away from being perfect, and that downvoter posted his tiny modification as an answer.  I upvoted him and accepted, but this is the kind of crapola that I'm getting pretty tired of and am more and more considering SO to best be read only

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Speaking in terms of author rights not ownership rights. I'm assuming that was already clear from my question since you started your comment with "Technically". If you don't think it's clear let me know and I can clarify the question.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I dunno about that, I'd say upvoting and accepting these answers encourages them, which is not a healthy thing for http://steckoverflow.com as you have said.

Comment: @JonathanMee, didn't realize my answer caused such an upset for you. The only reason I posted it, is that the OP specifically asked for "some elegant one liner" and neither answer had that. I've taken your idea of using / and % and wrote my own answer. Since the original idea was yours, I've added the "stolen" attribution. Also, your answer was downvoted -1, which I felt was unfair, so I've upvoted it. Lastly, to make up for your loss, I've checked some of your questions/answers and upvoted the ones I liked. If you still feel upset, let me know and I can just delete my answer.

Comment: @InnocentBystander if I understood [this comment above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325862/should-i-flag-an-answer-that-basically-just-links-to-my-answer#comment355562_325862) correctly the question was posted when Jonathan was under the impression the code was identical.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson _Technically_ that's **incorrect**. The author maintains ownership of the code, but grants a license to SO (and others).

Comment: @JonathanMee: Heh, so if the poster of that answer had bothered to explain even a little bit, it would have flagged up the small difference in the code for you, and you wouldn't have thought it was purely a duplicate of your code. Definitely a low-effort answer.

Comment: @InnocentBystander Nope, you were right to post it. [I didn't realize](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325862/should-i-flag-an-answer-that-basically-just-links-to-my-answer#comment355562_325862) that you'd changed the `for_each` to a `for`-loop when I opened this post. If you could edit with a little explanation of how you changed it that may help others from falling into my mistaken assumption though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***I don't believe it's a link only answer, [nor plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318338/3956566)***, however annoying it is. As there is code in the answer, with a link for more info and there is attribution given to the original author.

The work on SO is allowed to be reproduced with attribution. So if it's on SO, to the original author, if it's not on SO, to SO and possibly the author.

I can't see the answer you are referring to, if it is an exact dupe, then as Servy says, flag it as an exact dupe.

In terms of flagging, the only suitable flag would be a custom mod flag if it is an exact dupe. [*(Which it is not).*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727381/is-there-some-stl-function-to-get-cartesian-product-of-two-c-vectors/37729622#37729622)

The following as cited by [Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251398/3956566), originally by [Pekka 웃](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka-%EC%9B%83) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251390/3956566)

> "Is it considered plagiarism on StackOverflow.com to take material from another answer on the same question and re-use it with modifications?
>
> No. You are expressly permitted to do so - as long as you give attribution."

*very dry sense of humour here :D*

Comment: Yeah it's not plagiarism. It *might as well be* a link-only answer - the quotation protects it from being link-only, but it is still a low-effort answer. Basically, use your common sense and state the problem clearly when flagging. Don't weasel it.

Comment: @BoltClock what do you mean don't weasel it? I am reluctant to flag as link only http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319350/should-link-only-accepted-answers-remain-on-the-site  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318919/how-long-should-a-mod-wait-before-reviewing-flags-for-the-low-quality-queue-to-g

Comment: i.e. don't say it's a link-only answer, don't say it's NAA, don't say it's plagiarism - just state plainly that "this answer consists of nothing but a quotation of an existing answer" for best results.

Comment: @BoltClock yeh, but I've had a lot of flags declined for answers like that. Although I agree we don't need them on the site, I cannot recommend people to flag when they may well be declined. See links above.

Comment: @BoltClock The answer contains "orginal" code.  The code the users has is a modified version of the OP's code.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes! see the edit! great minds and all that

Comment: @NathanOliver: If the answer we're discussing is a derivative work of the source answer, I agree that's fine, since obviously the author put effort into remixing it.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes it is a derivative.  They used the same concept but did modify it somewhat.  Not sure exactly what the line is but this one looks like it is on the okay side of the line.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Definitely.

Answer (score 9):

No, you should not flag it.

It was easy to find [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729622/1997232) you mentioned and it looks like improved (different) version of your answer:

1. Your answer was used as an idea (this is specifically mentioned, so no plagiarism here).
2. It's different (`for` instead of `for_each`) and take less lines (the reason why answerer decided to post his answer I guess).

It doesn't fall to link-only category neither: it references your answer as an original source and only wrote what will be different. The link to his working sample is here to prove what the final code will work, you still have your credits.

P.S.: I have added explicit reference to your answer in his answer.

P.P.S: You can edit other people answers ;)

Comment: The critical part here is "2. It's different". Otherwise, where would be the value of just duplicating an answer (giving or not giving credit)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should flag that answer as plagiarism. When quoting someone else it's important that it be a part of the answer that also includes original contributions of the author, and not the entirety if the answer.

Note that the answer isn't a *link only* answer. It does answer the question.  You should not be flagging it as NAA.

If you feel that your answer is also a suitable answer to the question, then flag the question for closure as a duplicate while you're at it.

Comment: It is not plagiarism, plagiarism is using another's work without attribution and purporting it to be your own.

Comment: [Dictionary definition of plagiarism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plagiarism). Not applicable here.

Comment: @Yvette That's *one* way of plagiarizing content.  It's not the only way to plagiarize content.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett [And here's another definition of plagiarism](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/) that *does* specifically define this as plagiarism.  "copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not "

Comment: That's based on the USA definition of copyright.  Can't apply, you implicitly handed over the right for anybody to copy the work by posting to SO.  Only proper attribution is required.  It wasn't proper in the quoted answer but that's very easy to fix of course, took me 20 seconds.

Comment: @hans no, your talking copyright.  Plagiarism is different.  You can plagiarize content without violating any laws, such as copyright.

Comment: At least that article you linked to is based on a very specific law that helps people interpret what plagiarism means.  What you invoke in your answer looks merely based on your personal preferences.