# Yet another "Why was my NAA-flag declined?" question

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

My NAA flag on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313975/4792869) answer was declined yesterday. For me it is a link-only answer (it is useless without the link), so I don't understand why it was declined. Was the moderator maybe distracted by the formatting? (it looks like if it contained code, but it does not)
Is it because it is accepted?

Additional question: Should I have raised a custom flag to avoid the reviewer(s) judging based on the formatting?

---

Screenshot of the answer:

[image]

Comment: *"link-only **answer**"*, so it does go under "answer". Just flag it as VLQ

Comment: According to this meta post it is NAA, because it does not answer the question if it is stripped down to plain text: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4792869

Comment: Time to merge the flags? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one

Comment: Somebody can very easily bang that accepted answer into shape.  The odds that anybody is going to destroy an accepted answer that has been around for 4 years, verified by hundreds of programmers and is still perfectly valid are never very good.  Hopefully that is kinda obvious to any SO user.  Just don't ask somebody else to do it for you, fix it yourself.

Comment: It helped the op, so it cant be not-an-answer for everyone

Comment: @Ferrybig a helpful comment should still be a comment. (I agree with Hans Passant however that I rather should have edited the relevant part of the linked website into the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, you're right here. The code formatting (and relatively long length) threw me off. It's borderline, but still decidedly on the link-only side of the border.

I've deleted it now, and offer my apologies for declining your flag.

Comment: Ah, the participation of 548 users destroyed.  Take no half measures to keep up the high SO standard, only way to keep the quality we all seek.  Surely you can get the question count back to less than 10 million when you aim right.  Please aim right.