# Missing standard flag for link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

So far I've flagged dozens of link-only answers with a 100% approve rate.

Couple of days back I clicked to flag [one such answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238177/capture-any-type-of-camera-in-qt/18238493#18238493) just to find out that I've already flagged it a week ago and it was declined:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and
>   resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of
>   standard flags: see What is Flagging?

Fair enough, I followed the link and read through, but I did not find any standard flag about link-only answers. And it goes without saying, if there was such an option to begin with I'd have used it. None of the available options are IMO accurate - it was not "not an answer" and it was not "very low quality", it certainly wasn't too "rude or abusive", and it wasn't spam either, it was simply a link-only answer, leaving me with the last option, which is "in need of moderator intervention" and although I admit that sounds a little drastic, it is the only option I could select without being overly inaccurate with the flag, for *"A problem not listed above (that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!")*, which again sounds a little drastic, but there was no *"A problem not listed above that doesn't require the precious time of a moderator who would rather decline accurate flags and waste even more on giving me pointless advises instead"* option.

[image]

But what was more striking is that the flag was declined not because it wasn't accurate, but because someone felt like it wasn't worthy of the time he volunteered to maintain the community. In fact the flag was very much accurate, not only is it obviously a link-only answer, but the author even explicitly admits to that as well as his unwillingness to do better.

So I flagged it again, just to have it declined again, encouraging me once again to familiarize myself with the non-existent standard flag for link only answers. And yet now I see that the answer was actually converted to a comment following the second declined flag, so if the flag led to an action, why was it declined.

Should a moderator decline an accurate flag?

Should a moderator tell me to familiarize with non-existent standard flags?

Should a moderator decline a flag which led to an action nonetheless?

And lastly, can we have a standard flag for link-only answers?

Comment: Answer which are *really* link-only can be flagged as ['not an answer'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: VLQ if the link is valid, NAA if it's dead

Comment: If this flag was declined, we should perhaps update the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4751173), which states *If you do find a link-only answer (especially one with a dead link), it is probably better to use the other flag and explain to the moderators why the post should be deleted.*

Comment: *And lastly, can we have a standard flag for link-only answers?* Please, no. 2 flags (NAA and VLQ) that have the same meaning and workflow is already confusing enough to everyone: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one Let's not add a third for exactly the same purpose.

Comment: @Glorfindel for the sake of precision there's a notable exception for this rule - when question itself asks for links official ["castle" guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773) disallows NAA and requires closing the question instead. Per my reading of the question in question though this is not the case here, it doesn't explicitly ask for links so NAA qualifies

Comment: @gnat correct, but even then NAA flags are often marked helpful. For example, I got two of them today on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138110/api-for-school-management-system/40890436#40890436) (10k only).

Comment: A link to an answer is not an answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant - it is not a link to an answer, but to documentation

Comment: The point is that the answer is not in the answer, it is on the other side of the link. If there is no answer *in* the answer, it is not an answer, regardless of what is on the other end of whatever links may be contained in the answer.