# Why was a proper flag declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972657/copying-creating-mdf-files-in-sql-server-folder-during-setup-of-c-sharp-windows/42550083#42550083) as NAA (**N**ot **A**n **A**nswer), the "answer" is:

> what if i have connected to database with LINQ?!!

It was declined as:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

It was

- NOT a [rhetorical post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131959/should-i-not-flag-a-rhetorical-question-posted-as-an-answer) for it to be declined as such
- NOT on a bad question [to be declined as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).
- belongs to the second category in [Martijn's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) on [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

  Are there any [new rules or regulations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344614/why-were-my-flags-declined-but-the-flagged-comments-removed) which I need to follow or am I missing something else?

Comment: Looks like the answer has now been deleted. I would have flagged the same and quite rightly. That is definitely NAA.

Comment: Can 10K users see the timeline of the post? It was propably reviewed wrongly.

Comment: @S.L.Barth reviewers can't decline flags and in the declined statement is pretty clear who interacted with flag. I love'em but sometimes they confuse me.

Comment: Hm yes, the message suggests it was someone with a diamond. I guess somebody mis-clicked.

Comment: Lets hope, that way I will clear my taught's again and continue flagging as usual, I'm just a bit worry about some strange VLQ vs NAA stuff.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

My mistake, sorry. I misread the post as being rhetorical, and almost immediately realised I got it wrong, then deleted the post.

[image: paper bag on head]

I can't change the declined flags; I would if I could!

Mea Culpa.

Comment: No problem thanks for answer, keep up the good work!

Comment: If you see a rhetorical question: edit it. That way it looks like an answer, or not.

Comment: Nice bag ...... :/

Comment: That's a pretty horrible ninja mask ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Guess what is worn underneath the paper bag? `[-_-]~`

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"Guess what is worn underneath the paper bag?"* - [My *wild* guess...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BBZVQ4zBcU)