# Why were these "no longer needed" comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

My comment flagging record is pretty good. Today, I flagged numerous comments as "no longer needed" on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101739/1497596). While 2 of my flags *were* accepted, to my surprise 10 were declined. (My guess is that the two that were accepted were ones that were auto-accepted.) While I cannot distinguish those that were declined from those that were accepted, here are the comments that I flagged:

- solved the problem
- Best answer!!!!
- Fantastic ! It's what is working for me ! thanks !
- This is the answer.
- thx u guys glad it help u
- That solved my issue. Thank you :)
- worked for me too
- this one is the real deal
- it worked for me...

Based on my past experience, I do not think there is anything remotely controversial about whether any of these comments deserved be flagged. Have the flagging guidelines changed? Is it possible that the moderator that declined these flags holds the belief that handling flags of this nature is not the best use of their time?

Comment: A good SO janitor is always needed, if you have time and fun you are welcome to join us in [SOBotics Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), hunting NAA, offensive comments, plagiarism, bad edits etc.

Comment: That's pretty cringy IMHO... Isn't it allowed to say 'thank you' to people who helped you out?

Comment: @O'Niel No, because SO is not a discussion board or forum. Say thanks by upvoting a question or answer.

Comment: @O'Niel sure (even if a upvote or accept is better), but after awhile it should go, to clean up all these useless comment for future users. There is even a nice hat for you if you do it by yourself ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I apologize. It was a mistake, not an intended change in policy.

I meant to approve your flags, but misread "decline" as "delete" and clicked the wrong button.

Comment: Perhaps a flag review ban is in order - perhaps seven days? Take some time out to think about the procedures and how you will do it better next time.

Comment: Meant to upvote, flagged instead.

Comment: @Jeremy Given the workload that moderators face on an ongoing basis, I can certainly understand how this can happen from time-to-time. Unfortunately for me, those 10 declined flags double my declined flag count. :-( But I won't ask about having those declined flags reversed, as I understand that [moderators don't have the authority to make this kind of change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344792/1497596). But that's OK...I'll keep fighting the good fight as a devoted member of the SO cleanup crew.

Comment: ...And by the way, I'm happy to see that the comments I flagged have now been deleted.

Comment: You could still change those flags to disputed, right?

Comment: @NisargShah, No you can't change any declined flags into disputed (comment flags cannot be disputed at all). The red flags can be disputed after declining (for which there's a hacky procedure).

Comment: Out of curiosity how does moderator interface (UI) looks like? Maybe blame some programmers (as always)? ;)

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: You misread it 10 times?

Comment: @TravisJ Happens more often than that. It's usually all one below the other, so you misread the first, you misread the remaining. I dunno how Jeremy stopped at 10, usually it stops at 50 (page size) :p (The UI is not that great, but it's quite good for what it is).