# Flag seems to be handled incorrect

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

So I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58091171/10070647) as 'Not an answer'. At least to me it definitely is not an answer see the comment under my answer.

> Hi, your answer is useful for me thank u so much.. my am not expert in linq query.. can you please see my below code. i have achieved my desire output but i think my logic is not optimize.. **i have post an answer will you please check this?**

Which definitely is an indication of it not being an answer. But my flag got marked as 'disputed'. Which means, at least to me, that at least someone agrees with the flag and someone didn't find evidence to support the case.

I would be interested why this is the case, or if the answer could be flagged as 'Not an answer'. Or should I flag the answer as 'in need of moderator intervention' with the described problem?

Comment: Related to [Why were my flags declined but the flagged comments removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344614/6381711), [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/6381711) and [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/6381711).

Comment: that answer looks like an answer, and if that is the code that now works for them, makes it an answer. They should have asked a new question but that needs more substance, like what "optimize" means and then it might even need to go on CodeReview if there isn't an actual coding problem to solve.

Comment: OP posted the code that that solves the problem posted in the question. The answer itself looks like an attempt at addressing the problem in the question, so it shouldn't be flagged or deleted. The comment on your answer sounds like he may be confusing SO for a forum, but despite that, his answer is still within the rules

Comment: To me it seems that it should be a new question instead since the following line `but i think my logic is not optimize..`. At least it should be edited.

Comment: I've seen many answers containing something along the lines of "The below code is ugly / inefficient / not optimized for X", but there's nothing wrong with that. If the answer contained a *question* in addition to code, that'd be an issue, but it doesn't.

Comment: Well then, I guess I got to obscured by the language used. Thanks anyway!

Comment: "Can you please see my below code […] will you please check this?" sounds to me like a vague request for further help, not a statement that a solution was reached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, let's review this as if we were reviewers. You flagged as Not An Answer and we're in the Low Quality Post queue where we judge if content needs to be deleted or not.

This is all of the answer you see:

[image]

- neutral score
- there is code
- the code has comments
- those comments explain what the code is doing
- maybe the code needs one indent less, and the i needs to be capitalized
- Opening remark seems to indicate the code works
- That first sentence triggers that we check the question
- self answered

This is an answer that works for the OP. No action is needed. Move to next review.

---

With that out of the way you state as a reason for it being not an answer

> At least to me it definitely is not an answer see the comment under **my** answer.

(emphasis mine).

As you can see from my workflow on that review I never get to see your answer. You either should have left a comment under the answer you flagged to provide me with context and you better down vote as well to signal to reviewers that the answer is not useful. Alternatively use a custom flag and explain why that answer should deleted but in this case I doubt a mod would follow your flag as it would need subject matter expertise to be 100% sure it isn't an answer.

Your flag was rightfully declined.

Comment: Alright then, this makes sense to me and I will do that the next time I encounter a similar issue. Thanks for your investigation.