# It's impossible to retract VLQ flag if someone up-votes post after flag

Tags: bug, flags, retracted-flags

Monitoring Stack Overflow, I saw an unregistered user posting answer with a link to a blog, which lead me to raise a VLQ flag, user posted same answer on other post (another VLQ flag and comment), then he/she went again and it was time to start to hover the spam flag.

I went back to first answer and saw it was upvoted, this lead me to want to raise a custom mod flag on the answer.

**However, this is impossible.**

My flag is pending:

[image: Pending flag]

So I should retract this flag, but since it's up-voted I can not the VLQ flag option is not available, but the flag interface lets me raise another flag.

[image: Impossibile to retract]

but if I try to submit custom moderator flag as above I get.

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention

[image: Already flagged]

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't let you have an option to retract the flag at all or that it does but then doesn't allow you?

Comment: @Jon it does not let me to retract the flag, probably since the VLQ flag is not an option when post is up voted and since I can't retract when I try to flag (as in screen shot) it shows above error

Comment: I think it's just a bug with VLQ flag on post that gets upvoted and do note this is just a bug report, naturally I know that I can flag other posts if this meta was not enough.

Comment: Does retraction show as an option again if you downvote it? (put it into a state where flagging it as such was valid?)

Comment: *Sorry, deleted I was too slow to test that*, I think however it's pretty simple to reproduce, if you need some VLQ posts to test on just give me a ping :). The sequenze is flag VLQ, someone upvote, then try to retract and/or flag something else.

Comment: While at it let me promote what I think is the final solution to this bug [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/5292302) :D

Comment: The new bug could be that it show possibility to flag with other option, but I prefer duplicate since the core issue is the same.

Comment: If the answer has only one upvote you can downvote it, then the VLQ option shows up again and you can retract it. And when you're done you can un-downvote within the grace period.