# Unable to retract a VLQ flag

Tags: support, bug, flags

In regards to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48483275/1415724) that was posted for:

- [How to get Request Referer PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483195/how-to-get-request-referer-php)

that I later closed as a duplicate, tried flagging for moderation using the following message:

> I wanted to retract my (still pending) flag as VLQ (from yesterday) but I don't see the option to retract as I normally do and I didn't want to post on meta about this, since it will most likely not be well-taken. Can you tell me why I can't retract the flag? However, the link only answer to an already asked question is still that; a link only and that is why I originally flagged as being VLQ.

But then I see a red popup message showing me:

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention.

which I didn't raise a flag for moderation and find it rather odd since I flagged it as VLQ (very low quality) given it is a link only answer to an existing Q&A.

Why is that and why was I not able to retract my flag?

I did find the following post here on meta

- [It's impossible to retract VLQ flag if someone up-votes post after flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358584/its-impossible-to-retract-vlq-flag-if-someone-up-votes-post-after-flag)

I should be able to retract my flag under any circumstances, right?

That above meta contains comments that state it is a bug, so why hasn't that bug been fixed yet?

**Edit:** (after being marked as a duplicate)

After downvoting (and retracting) my downvote for it, noticed that I was able to retract my flag. The question still remains though that I feel I should have been able to retract my flag under any circumstance.

I feel the duplicate doesn't answer my question nor am I given any support for this, seeing my question here was hammered by a moderator.

What does this have to do with a user script to be installed?

The popup message does NOT address the flag; so is that just some generic message? Shouldn't it address the actual "VLQ" flag?

Comment: You can only have a single pending flag on any given post at a time. The error message was simply informing you that you already have a pending flag, not informing you of a specific type of flag that you have cast in the past. Not being able to *retract* the flag is a known bug that simply has yet to be fixed.

Comment: @animuson The thing is here, that this wasn't flagged for moderation `You have already flagged this post for moderator attention.` and feel that the popup is misleading. So, should this be a feature request instead, or and `and/or`? This whole thing has me confused and I should have been able to retract the flag under any circumstance, whether it was upvoted/downvoted or not. I also edited my post and voted to reopen.

Comment: All flags are flags for moderator attention. They bring the attention of moderators to the post...

Comment: @animuson this bug has been present for a year or **years**. One has to wonder why it hasn't been fixed yet. They fixed many other bugs, so why not this one? Now you're saying that all bugs are for moderation attention. I was under the impression that VLQ's are dealt with under reviewers; so I take it that those are "also" send to mods; correct?

Comment: VLQ and NAA flags drop posts into the Low Quality Posts queue, yes, but they are still visible to moderators after 15 minutes of activity, and can still get their attention (as well, a post that has previously been through LQP cannot go through the queue again, so all further flags of those types will *only* go to moderators).  I get that the bug has existed for a while, but that's not a reason to keep creating additional bug reports for it.

Comment: @animuson I understand. Ok, thanks. However, it'd be an easy fix wouldn't it to change that popup message, or is to be left alone as it is? I just thought it was confusing in light of the flag itself as VLQ rather than a mod flag, which in theory is that as you said but you can see where I was caught by surprise by it.

Comment: If you think the error message is confusing and the wording should be changed, you may want to open a separate feature request about just that part.