# Low quality flag declined, answer deleted

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

My very low quality flag was declined. When I clicked to look at it and learn from the experience I was super confused for a minute.  I was brought to a highly upvoted question that I would never have flagged for very low quality. So I went back to the review screen and saw that it was an answer I had flagged. I quickly discovered that the answer in question was deleted.

So I guess it must have been deleted for another reason than being very low quality. I don't have 10K rep so I can't view deleted answers. So can someone who does have this privilege let me know where I went wrong here? I'm just trying to learn from my mistakes.

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Change to Theme.AppCompat causes other error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180052/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity-chan/48120990#48120990)

[image: Screenshot of the declined notification]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That answer was simultaneously flagged as "not an answer". A moderator reviewed that flag and declined it, causing the "very low quality" flag to be declined at the same time.

However, at almost the exact same time [it was in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18437972) and acquired the last delete vote it needed to be removed.

My guess is that the moderator disagreed with it being labeled as a non-answer, but it was of sufficiently low quality that the community thought it should be deleted. There was a minor collision there in terms of timing, probably a consequence of the flag queue being very low right now.

Comment: Hmm okay, that's strange that declining a not an answer flag would also decline a very low quality flag given that those have different criteria.

Comment: I did not accidentally decline the VLQ flag. I still apply the criteria for VLQ here: that a post is so low quality as to be unreadable. The post was readable just fine. Moderators can handle flags on a post separately (usually, there are some corner cases but they didn’t apply here) but I explicitly choose to handle both flags together here.

Comment: Put differently: VLQ should really not be used on something that is merely of low quality. That’s what voting is for. VLQ should only be used on posts that deserve to be deleted right now, because they are so useless as to not make any sense.

Comment: It's always the same story isn't it? Moderators and the community disagree on what constitutes being of low enough quality to be deleted (i.e. hidden from public view potentially *indefinitely*, because I know some people will go "but you can always undelete something" as if that was ever relevant to the discussion). So as much as we tell people not to use VLQ except on things that are unintelligible garbage, I have to wonder if the community is secretly opposed to that, given how happy they are to delete something that's simply "mediocre" or "not good enough" and not "completely unusable".

Comment: @BoltClock: simple: Moderators don't make technical calls on posts. We don't handle 'wrong' answers, full stop.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I'm not referring to wrong answers. I'm referring to acceptable answers that get deleted just because they were poorly written (yet still readable enough) or they didn't contain enough words, or code. Answers that "should be a comment" just because they weren't fleshed-out.

Comment: @BoltClock: sounds the same to me. Someone deems it not *enough* of an answer. We don't make that call.

Comment: @BoltClock There isn't a flag for short answers.  Answers are not supposed to be posted as comments just because they're short.  Comments are not for answers; comments are a place to help the author of a post improve it, and a short answer is not that.  If you feel that *an answer to the question* isn't fleshed out, and is therefore not a quality answer, you can reflect that opinion with a vote, because that's exactly what votes are for.  Using VLQ as a second downvote isn't what it's there for.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure why this is being addressed to me tbh, but it's exactly what all the people using VLQ/NAA for short answers and recommending deletion when reviewing them need to hear.

Comment: @BoltClock My apologies, I misunderstood you explaining a behavior as advocating for it. I've simply seen too many people actually advocating that exact thing.

Comment: Time to [merge the flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one) and make it more simple?, the VLQ flag is just crazy (helpful even if edited by OP, but with an automatic down vote, baah)