# Why was this VLQ flag in a link-only answer declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, specific-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072874) answer as very low quality, since it was a link-only answer. There was no context around the link - or actually there was, how helpful the link was.

Strangely, the flag was declined because a moderator reviewed it and found no evidence to support it. Here is a screenshot of it:

> [image]

What the OP describes in the rest of the post is the versions they used, but what they did using them was in the link they included.

So, why was my flag declined?

Comment: It should *not* have been declined, and I'd like to hear the moderator's rationale for their action.

Comment: It entered the [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22977260) - the review was invalidated with one user recommending deletion.

Comment: I think you should have used a NAA flag instead of VLQ. Can't remember the source but VLQ if for things like total gibberisch and foreign languages.

Comment: @AndréKool nope, it doesn't have a difference. I use VLQ on these, since if OP edits (which is most likely to happen), the flag will be cleared.

Comment: @AndréKool: no, the answer *does* attempt to answer the question, admittedly in poor fashion, but nevertheless, it's an attempt, and so NAA is not appropriate here. VLQ OTH is.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's basicly a link-only answer and an NAA flag is [appropriate here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: @double-beep From the flag text itself : _This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed._ My understanding is that if it can be saved by an edit you should not be using a VLQ flag at all.

Comment: @AndréKool wrong, if it can be saved with an edit, it should be flagged VLQ. OP edits → NAA flag not cleared → mod declined.

Comment: Related question (to the comments, not to this question) [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/1364007).

Comment: Just downvote it. Why do you need a flag?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I cannot understand your point. Link-only answers aren't appropriate and downvoting don't bring them to the community.

Comment: What do we do when we see a bad answer? We downvote it. No need for all this flagging. Once there are enough downvotes we can start delete-voting if it's really harmful. This is a storm in a teacup. Worry about something more important!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's a defensible philosophy on its own, but one that seems inconsistent with having the VLQ or NAA flags at all. Given that they exist, and given that posts like this are normally taken to be the sort of thing that they're for, asking why a moderator declined this flag is reasonable.

Comment: Most of my declines are on VLQ flags. I've basically been told not to use those flags, because it implies "unsalvageable" which... usually they are. Which is silly. It doesn't answer this -- but i just don't use the flag anymore because it's incredibly ambiguous

Comment: 5 bucks says the flag got declined because, *"This is working in Swift 4."*, was interpreted as, "The OP's code works in Swift 4", not, "The tutorial above works in Swift 4." Someone misunderstood the answer as saying the linked tutorial shows that the asker just needs to upgrade their version of Swift. (Or maybe that *is* actually what they were trying to say.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your response to "Why was this flag incorrectly declined" is "Don't flag things"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you suggesting we remove answer flags entirely then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure how else to interpret "Why do you need a flag?" If you meant something else, you didn't do a very good job of explaining yourself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fwiw your comments are valid. There's more than one way to remove content off the site.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery _"Why do you need a flag [in this case]?"_ is not the same as _"Why do we need flags at all ever for anything?"_

Comment: this doesn't answer the question by itself. You have to follow the link. So it's not an answer, and should be flagged. You can add a complimentary downvote, you'll get your 1 rep back soon enough

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "What do we do when we see a bad answer? We downvote it. No need for all this flagging." If this answer doesn't deserve a flag, than what would? You never explain that.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - If, as appears to be the case, the VLQ flag is for answers that are unsalvageable, this answer was improperly flagged. The difference is in the "V" as in "Very". So, it might be considered a "Low Quality" answer, just not a "Very Low Quality" answer. Perhaps you know differently, but let's assume the linked information is "correct" and solves the OPs issue. So if that is the case, then at the moment, it IS a helpful answer. It's just not "optimal/desirable" because of the potential for future "link rot".  -->

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - And, also consider the answer writer is a new user and might not be fully aware of the issue. So, what's wrong with leaving a comment explaining the "link rot" issue and recommending the content at the link be copied into the answer so it is still a helpful answer if (okay, when) the link eventually goes dead. Then, the OP (or someone else) can edit that content into the answer. Or, make that edit yourself. Deleting (rather than editing) an answer that is a working solution, even if it's link-only/sub-optimal, doesn't help the OP or anyone who might find the question later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That was my fault! A total misread of the answer. Sorry!

[image]

Comment: Hey, nice glasses!

Comment: Upvoted and accepted because these glasses are better than @CodyGray 's ones.