# What flag to use for answers that say "use ChatGPT to fix your errors"?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, chatgpt

I just came across an answer post that (essentially) just said "*Use chatGPT to help correct your errors*" (To be fair, the answer had a tiny bit of actual information, but I would say nothing of real substance in relation to the error.).

I assume this is flag-worthy. How should I flag this?

- "Not an Answer" seems like a safe choice (and it's the choice I ended up going with (I wasn't thinking too hard about it at the time, and was in the middle of flagging a bunch of other non-answers))
- I'm wondering if answering like this is considered rude. To me, it seems analogous to writing an answer post saying "Just google it" in a pre-ChatGPT era, which to me, seems like a rude thing to do.
- "Very Low Quality" seems like a good choice too.

Which of those flag reasons is acceptable in such a scenario? Does one of them work best?

I'm going to avoid directly linking to that answer post to avoid the meta-effect.

Comment: As a side note, if it were a comment, I'd also flag it as "No longer needed".

Comment: I'd say "Use ChatGPT to fix your errors" looks quite a lot like [a sign pointing to an apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcpV2.png) :p (Image from this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553))

Comment: Re VLQ, see also e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952 . I think the interesting question here is just whether to treat such replies as rude. They definitely meet the NAA standard.

Comment: "Use ChatGPT" is the new "LMGTFY" ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel maybe we should go down the route of copy and pasting an answer from ChatGPT into the answers is "Rude" as the "author" (of the answer) is implying the user who asked the question is incapable of doing it themselves. ;)

Comment: @ThomA Copying and pasting the answer is already banned by a separate, special rule. The current discussion is about *suggesting that OP should* do so, rather than just attempting an answer. ""Use ChatGPT" is the new "LMGTFY" ;)" - I think this argument has weight; and on this basis, I lean towards such answers being "rude", since they would therefore be rude as comments.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *"Copying and pasting the answer is already banned by a separate, special rule."* that isn't enforceable anymore; making it pointless. (Though a completely separate subject to what is being asked)

Comment: The moderator strike doesn't change what the correct flags are, and IMO shouldn't change the flagging behaviour of ordinary users.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That same answer says `Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer`. Which neatly contradicts the very image you've posted, and based on my flags has been interpreted by mods to mean "don't ever delete an answer unless it's obvious spam". By that same "logic", _any "answer" that says "use ChatGPT" is valid_.

Comment: @IanKemp That's the *exact* reason I stopped using the "Not an answer" flag (*save for "obvious spam"*), since it's completely unclear what *that* actually means or that it is open to mod interpretation; it's too much to scroll up to the question to get a little context to see that not everything that finds its way into the answer box is a valid attempt. Since it's provided as an answer it's assumed to have *some* sliver of "attempt to answer", regardless how off the mark it may be.

Comment: @DrewReese "not an answer" is for when the OP uses the "Answer" box to amend their question, for when someone asks for clarification (or even a whole new question) in the answer box to an old question, and similar cases. Anything that obviously is not trying to answer a question. Don't expect moderators  to have the time or subject knowledge to distinguish an answer from stuff that sort of looks like an answer. Just downvote, delete vote, and move on.

Comment: Use Chat GPT is an answer. It's a useless answer. Useless answers get downvotes and a delete vote if you have the rep. It's not something worth bothering the mods with.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't disagree that *that* is how NAA flags are exercised in practice, but the description of NAA doesn't describe any of those use cases. A point Ian makes is that if you follow the guidance the NAA provides it'll likely be declined, because terrible and completely useless, not-on-topic, answers are, well, *still answers*. I'm just agreeing with their comment there's a (*sizable*) rift between the guidance and actual practice and that *some* junk can just hang around a little longer until it gets voted down and/or deleted.

Comment: @DrewReese I see. Yes, fair point. Guidance is terrible because moderators often can't verify flag made according to the guidance, and have to decline it or at least ignore it.

Comment: What if the question posed by the OP is "I got this code from ChatGPT but it has errors, can you fix it for me?"

Comment: @kevin to quote your own example with emphasis added: "_can **YOU** fix it for me_". Saying "use ChatGPT to fix it" is the equivalent of saying "no I won't. fix it yourself." It's just a waste of everyone's time and contains no insight or actual useful information whatsoever.

Comment: It’s actually worse than saying “google it” because Google points to resources that at least until recently were created by humans, often with verifiable expertise. ChatGPT on the other hand is an expert BS’er that sometimes gets things right but often totally makes them up, with no way to know when it will give correct information a priori. It’s the worst of both worlds: an appearance of extreme expertise with a complete lack of reliability. If ChatGPT replaces Google, we’re all going to suffer…

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Flag as "Not an answer"

It is not an answer.  It is a suggestion as to where an answer might be found, but it is not, itself, an answer, any more than a suggestion to use a search engine would be.

I wouldn't suggest a "Rude or abusive" flag unless it's something like "Ugh this is so lazy, you should have asked ChatGPT before bothering us with this stupid question."

Comment: I too would have flag it as **Not An Answer**, since it shows little or no effort in answering, hence I don't think it fits in a Q&A website. However, I think it's just as rude as "LMGTFY" if not followed by at least a brief explanation of why, even if just a comment

Answer (score -11):

If the person is a real beginner (and if they're asking that, they might be), this kind of thoughts of 'searching' about on Google or ChatGPT doesn’t cross the mind. So I think it's kind of rude to answer that, considering that you’re more knowledgeable and once might have started from zero too.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. If using ChatGPT doesn't cross someone's mind, how is it rude to answer telling them to? If anything i'd have thought you'd say the opposite.

Comment: it's rude for the same reason LMGTFY was rude. but that doesn't mean it necessarily raises to the level of a R/A flag.

Comment: I feel this should be a comment, not an answer. Unless I'm misunderstanding, it boils down to "I agree, LMGTFY and 'use ChatGPT' is rude".

Comment: Is this answer proposing that the "Rude or abusive" flag should be used for such answers?