# Flagging system is unclear when it comes to link-only answers

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

As explained [in a Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251007/240613), link-only answers should be flagged:

> [...] since it requires you to go off-site to find a solution. We want solutions to be on the site. The answer should have been a comment. To be an answer, it should cite the relevant parts of the off-site resource instead.

Also [according to Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272984/240613), an answer which is a link-only answer should not be flagged as:

> **in need of moderator intervention**
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

because it is “taking time from mods”. This is understandable. Instead, one should chose:

> **not an answer**
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

However, this is unclear by simply looking at flag reasons descriptions. There are two problems here:

- “in need of moderator intervention” looks exactly as any other reason. Previously, I thought that all four reasons have equal severity and lead to the same procedure, meaning that I would chose the fourth one as a default choice, and so much more frequently than I should have.
- The description of “not an answer” excludes link-only answers, because it deals explicitly with the answers which “[do] not attempt to answer the question”: link-only answers do attempt to answer the question, and often answer it; the problem is not that they don't answer the question, but that Stack Exchange community wants the answer to be located *on* Stack Exchange sites, not on a third-party site.
- The rejection of the flag has a weird explanation: “declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer”. This doesn't inform the users properly about what they did wrong, and actually claims that link-only answers shouldn't be flagged at all, which is wrong.

Given the current descriptions, flagging a link-only answer as “in need of moderator intervention” *is* the intuitive response.

My suggestions are:

1. To highlight the fourth reason or to indicate in some other way that the first three are dealt with by the community, while the fourth one requires moderators attention and should be used with caution.
2. To change the description of “not an answer” to include link-only answers as well.
3. To change the decline explanation to “declined - link-only answers should be flagged as *not an answer* in order to be dealt directly by community; flagging a question to moderators should be done only in a case of a serious issue with the answer.”

Does it make sense?

Comment: "the first three are dealt with by the community" They're not, always. Mods can still review them via the queues like everyone else, and if they aren't resolved within a certain time limit they go to the mod-only queue anyways.

Comment: Related: [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one)

Answer (score 6):

[As I've said elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), *links* are not the problem... Answers that don't contain any information are the problem. Flagging to write "link only answer" does little or nothing to help the moderator decide whether or not there's reason to delete what they're looking at; you're better off just downvoting.

But in cases where the answer is *entirely bereft of information*, Not An Answer does apply: the critical problem then isn't the link, it's the lack of anything else. Adding a "links" clause to the flag wouldn't improve matters; linking to additional information is, as a general rule, *a very good thing indeed!* The only solution is to reset our perception of the problem.

Comment: With regards to "bereft of information", I believe this is where it is left open to interpretation and some of the source of the issue. If the answer is a one liner with some context and a link (still all included in just one line), does that mean it warrants a (potential) downvote but not a flag? That was my interpretation. However, there seems to also be the interpretation that a one liner with some context (probably still to brief to be of value) *is* bereft of information and thus eligible for the not an answer flag. The "elsewhere" link you provide also has a very similarly vague outlook.

Comment: In that it says "*Does that mean these answers should forever hang around the site? No, not necessarily - if it turns out they're just not that useful, they should probably still be removed*", critically the "not necessarily" aspect of that statement is where interpretation again enters. This would potentially be the root of the issue with users perceptions with regards to the NAA on link only answers problem.

Comment: I would rather *hope* this is open to interpretation, @Travis. When it's possible to judge these situations mechanically, we block such answers outright - so the only ones you see should be in some sort of a grey area (or ones obviously created to work around the automated restrictions).

Comment: VLQ would be a better fit than NAA. Then again, considering both flags put answers in the very same bin anyway, why do both options exist again?